# Joining result of SQL Query after not exists

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

The other day, I asked this post: [SQL - Returning all rows that are not 'vice versa' of one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69065949/sql-returning-all-rows-that-are-not-vice-versa-of-one-another)

The basic setup was that I had a table houses, created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE houses (
    id character varying(24) NOT NULL,
    bit is_nice NOT NULL
);
```

and a larger table called house_listings, created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE house_listings(
    id character varying(24) NOT NULL,
    house_one character varying(24) NOT NULL,
    house_two character varying(24) NOT NULL,
    for_sale bit NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (house_one, house_two),
    FOREIGN KEY (house_one) REFERENCES houses(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (house_two) REFERENCES houses(id)
);
```

I'm extracting data from the two tables with a command suggested in the answer to the question:

```
select hl.*
from house_listings hl
where not exists (select 1
                  from house_listings hl2
                  where hl2.house_one = hl.house_two and
                        hl2.house_two = hl.house_one
                 );
```

My question is, after this I am left with a table, such as:

```
+------------------------+-------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| id                     | house_one         | house_two              | for_sale     |
+------------------------+-------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| vW4eNAC7jgZVxWAGxH4xAR | 7777              | 12345                  | 0x00         |
+------------------------+-------------------+------------------------+--------------+
```

My question is as follows: Is there a way to only return values from this query where `house_one` has an `is_nice` value of true? I tried JOINing the result of the overall query with houses, but SQL kept throwing a syntax error, so is this something that would need to be done earlier in the query, rather than later?

Thanks

Comment: Currently your question is only showing "what is working" but you're suppose to show "what is not working". The real issue here is that your attempted `JOIN` query is returning syntax error but you didn't post the attempted query nor the error that comes with it. Please update your question with relevant info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add this condition to the outer query:

```
select hl.*
from house_listings hl join
     houses h
     on hl.house_one = h.id
where h.is_nice = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from house_listings hl2
                  where hl2.house_one = hl.house_two and
                        hl2.house_two = hl.house_one
                 );
```

Comment: many thanks this did the trick! my mistake was that I was trying to add the condition to the inner query instead of the outer one